# TLS 1.2 support with SHA 1 certificate

Tags: security, ssl, weblogic, sha1, tls1.2

Need to know if we can enable TLS 1.2 cipher suites for SHA1 certificates for communication with managed servers in weblogic Application server?

Comment: This would be better asked at security.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

> enable TLS 1.2 cipher suites for SHA1 certificates

There is no such thing as a cipher suite for SHA1 certificates.

The cipher suite only specifies the authentication method which essentially specifies the type of certificate to use, i.e. typically RSA or ECDSA. The cipher suite itself makes no restrictions on the signature algorithm usable in the certificate, although such restrictions might be given in the TLS handshake using the [Signature Algorithms](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.1.4.1) extension in the TLS handshake - but this is not part of the cipher.

The cipher suite still contains some hash algorithm. But this is not used to specify the signature algorithm but instead the hash used inside the HMAC, i.e. message integrity and not authentication.

Answer (score 1):

The digest algorithm that was used to sign your server certificate has no influence whatsoever on the TLS version that you want to use.

So short answer: Yes, you can use a X.509 certificate that was signed using SHA-1 for a TLS v1.2 session

The problem with SHA-1 based certificates is on the client side. The client (ususally: web browser) has to decide wether it trusts the server's certificate or not. And most current browsers do not trust any SHA-1 certificates anymore, no matter if the session uses TLS 1.2 or an older version.